# jquery find closest textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Try to find the value of the textbox next to the radiobutton "no" checked, but failed.

```
$("form input:radio[value=False]:checked").closest(".txt").first().val();
```

the html code is like below:

```
    <span id="RadioButtonList1" style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">
    <input id="RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" value="true" />
    <label for="RadioButtonList1_0">Yes</label>
    <input id="RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList1" **value="False" checked="checked"** />
    <label for="RadioButtonList1_1">No</label>
</span>
<span id="RequiredFieldValidator1" style="visibility:hidden;">*</span>
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" value="pp" id="TextBox1" Class="txt" />
<br />
<span id="RadioButtonList2" style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">
    <input id="RadioButtonList2_0" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList2" value="true" checked="checked" />
    <label for="RadioButtonList2_0">Yes</label>
    <input id="RadioButtonList2_1" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList2" value="False" />
    <label for="RadioButtonList2_1">No</label>
</span>
<span id="RequiredFieldValidator2" style="visibility:hidden;">*</span>
<input name="TextBox2" type="text" id="TextBox2" Class="txt" />
<br />
<span id="RadioButtonList3" style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">
    <input id="RadioButtonList3_0" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList3" value="true" checked="checked" />
    <label for="RadioButtonList3_0">Yes</label>
    <input id="RadioButtonList3_1" type="radio" name="RadioButtonList3" value="False" />
    <label for="RadioButtonList3_1">No</label>
</span>
<span id="RequiredFieldValidator3" style="visibility:hidden;">*</span>
<input name="TextBox3" type="text" id="TextBox3" Class="txt" /><br />
```

Comment: have you tried .nextAll() instead of .closest()?  this is what I would use to find the next element in the dom matching the criteria.

Comment: @MikeLong `.closest` will match the closest parent element of the radio. Use `.parent().nextAll('.txt').first()`

Comment: yes, I did but failed.

Comment: @hitautodestruct got "undefined"

Comment: @MikeLong Have a look at this [example](http://jsbin.com/ENayiPI/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:
    $("form input:radio[value=False]:checked").closest("input[type=text]").first().val();

Comment: Thanks, but got "undefined"

Comment: Try this $("form input:radio[value=False]:checked").siblings("input[type='text']").val();

Comment: Why I tried all these methods, they all turn out **"undefined"**

Answer (score 0):

The following may work: `$( "form input:radio[value=False]:checked" ).parent().next( ".txt" ).val();`

Essentially detect the required checkbox (as you already did), jump to the parent element and select the next element with class `.txt`.